# How does two-wavelength interferometry mitigate vibrations in density measurements?

Tags: laser, plasma-physics, interferometry

I am currently using interferometry to measure the density of a plasma. The interferograms are suffering from vibrations, and I know that two-wavelength interferometry may mitigate this. I am however confused as to how exactly this helps, as I have not been able to find a source that gives a detailed explanation. So far all I could find was that a shorter wavelength can be used to measure the vibration of the interferometer and longer wavelength to measure density.

Could someone please give me more details on how exactly this works and help to mitigate vibrations?

Comment: Hi, to get people to respond, please read thru some of the intro material on how to post questions.   You should, for example, provide into on just who suggested 2-$\lambda$ interferometry. Why didn't you ask them for more information, or look up the method on tech sites such as https://opg.optica.org/josaa/fulltext.cfm?uri=josaa-26-12-2503&id=188530  or better,  https://wp.optics.arizona.edu/jcwyant/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2016/08/ExtendedRangeTwo-WavelengthInterferometry.pdf

Comment: Hi, sorry, I have already read these articles prior to posting, but they do not answer my question (they only address dynamic range and unambigous range) of how two-wavelength interferometry (TWI) can be used to mitigate vibrations. I have been previously been referred to e.g. K. Muraoka's Laser-Aided Diagnostics of Plasma and Gases, but that book only talks about how to use TWI to measure the density of electrons and neutrals separately.